# Proof for $\boldsymbol{2}^{\mathbb{N}} \preceq \mathbb{R}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Define a function $\theta: \boldsymbol{2}^{\mathbb{N}} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\theta\left(f\right) = \left\{q \in \mathbb{Q}: q < \sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{f\left(i\right)}{10^{i}} \textrm{ for some } n \in \mathbb{N}\right\},
\end{equation*}
where $\mathbb{Q}$ is the set of rational numbers. I cannot come up with the proof that this $\theta$ is one-one. Can anyone provide thoughts?

P.S. It should be noted that $\boldsymbol{r} \in \mathbb{R}$ is defined as a Dedekind cut. The first problem was to show that the set $\left\{q \in \mathbb{Q}: q < \sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{f\left(i\right)}{10^{i}} \textrm{ for some } n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$ is a Dedekind cut, which I proved myself.  The function $\theta$ is used in proving $\boldsymbol{2}^{\mathbb{N}} \preceq \mathbb{R}$.

---

I have organized a proof based on comments from this post. It goes as follows.

First we shall prove the following statement:

> For all $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$, if $m > n$, then
> \begin{equation*}
> \frac{1}{10^{n}} > \sum_{i=n+1}^{m}\frac{1}{10^{i}} + \frac{5}{10^{n+1}}.
> \end{equation*}

I am using mathematical induction to prove this statement. First define the following set with a fixed $m \in \mathbb{N}$:
\begin{equation*}
A = \left\{ n \in \mathbb{N}: m > n \textrm{ implies } \frac{1}{10^{n}} > \sum_{i=n+1}^{m}\frac{1}{10^{i}} + \frac{5}{10^{n+1}} \right\}.
\end{equation*}
If $m = 0$, then $m > n$ has to be false, thus $m = 0$ trivially implies $A = \mathbb{N}$. Now assume that $m > 0$. For $n = 0$,
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{i = 1}^{m}\frac{1}{10^{i}} + 0.5 = \frac{\frac{1}{10}\left(1-\frac{1}{10^{m}}\right)}{\frac{9}{10}} + 0.5 = \frac{1-\frac{1}{10^{m}}}{9} + 0.5 < 1.5 = \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{11}{18} < 1 = \frac{1}{10^{0}}.
\end{equation*}
Thus, $0 \in A$. Further, assume that for an arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{10^{n}} > \sum_{i=n+1}^{m}\frac{1}{10^{i}} + \frac{5}{10^{n+1}}.
\end{equation*}
Now consider the case of $n + 1$.  If $m \leq n$, then trivially the induction relation holds at $n + 1$. If $m = n + 1$, then
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{i=n+1+1}^{m}\frac{1}{10^{i}} + \frac{5}{10^{n+1+1}} = \sum_{i=n+2}^{m}\frac{1}{10^{i}} + \frac{5}{10^{n+2}} = \frac{5}{10^{n+2}} < \frac{1}{10^{n+1}}.
\end{equation*}
The relation also holds at $n + 1$. If $m > n+1$, then multiplying $1/10$ on both sides of the induction hypothesis, we have
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{10^{n+1}} > \sum_{i=n+2}^{m}\frac{1}{10^{i}} + \frac{5}{10^{n+2}}.
\end{equation*}
We may conclude that for an arbitrary $m \in \mathbb{N}$, $0 \in A$ and an arbitrary $n \in A$ implies $n + 1 \in A$. Consequently, $A = \mathbb{N}$ for an arbitrary $m \in \mathbb{N}$.

Next we shall use the proved statement to prove that $\theta$ is one-one. Assume that $f_{1},f_{2} \in \boldsymbol{2}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $f_{1} \neq f_{2}$. Define the following set:
\begin{equation*}
S = \left\{n \in \mathbb{N}: f_{1}\left(n\right) \neq f_{2}\left(n\right)\right\}.
\end{equation*}
We have $S \neq \emptyset$ as $f_{1} \neq f_{2}$. Then assume that $n_{0} = \min{\left(S\right)}$. Then $n_{0}$ is the first index where $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ diverges. As $f_{1}, f_{2} \in \boldsymbol{2}^{\mathbb{N}}$, without loss of generality, assume $f_{1}\left(n_{0}\right) = 1$, $f_{2}\left(n_{0}\right) = 0$ and $f_{1}\left(n\right) = f_{2}\left(n\right)$ for all $n < n_{0}$. Then we can write
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{i=0}^{n_{0}}\frac{f_{1}\left(i\right)}{10^{i}} = s + \frac{f_{1}\left(n_{0}\right)}{10^{n_{0}}} = s + \frac{1}{10^{n_{0}}},
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
s = 
\begin{cases}
0,\ n_{0} = 0\\
\sum_{i=0}^{n_{0}-1}\frac{f_{1}\left(i\right)}{10^{i}},\ n_{0} > 0
\end{cases}.
\end{equation*}
Further, for an arbitrary $m > n_{0}$ we have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=0}^{m}\frac{f_{2}\left(i\right)}{10^{i}} &= s + \frac{f_{2}\left(n_{0}\right)}{10^{n_{0}}} + \sum_{i=n_{0}+1}^{m}\frac{f_{2}\left(i\right)}{10^{i}} = s + \sum_{i=n_{0}+1}^{m}\frac{f_{2}\left(i\right)}{10^{i}}\\
&\leq s + \sum_{i=n_{0}+1}^{m}\frac{1}{10^{i}} \leq s + \frac{1}{10^{n_{0}}} - \frac{5}{10^{n_{0}+1}} = \sum_{i=0}^{n_{0}}\frac{f_{1}\left(i\right)}{10^{i}}-\frac{5}{10^{n_{0}+1}}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
It can be seen that
\begin{equation*}
\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n_{0}}\frac{f_{1}\left(i\right)}{10^{i}}-\frac{5}{10^{n_{0}+1}}\right) \in {f_{1}}^{*}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n_{0}}\frac{f_{1}\left(i\right)}{10^{i}}-\frac{5}{10^{n_{0}+1}}\right) \not\in {f_{2}}^{*}.
\end{equation*}
As a result, $\theta\left(f_{1}\right) \neq \theta\left(f_{2}\right)$ for $f_{1} \neq f_{2}$ and $\theta$ is injective.

Comment: Is there a sup missing on the right-hand side?

Comment: No. It is from "classic set theory" by Derek Goldrei on page 154, in case you have the book to verify.

Comment: Then how is $\Bbb R$ the codomain of $\theta$?

Comment: Anyway, the proof would be something like: let $n$ be the first place where $f_1$ and $f_2$ differ, and consider $q = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f_1(i)/10^i + \frac12/10^n$.

Comment: The proof is just to show $\boldsymbol{2}^{\mathbb{N}} \preceq \mathbb{R}$. $\mathbb{R} \preceq \mathscr{P}\left(\mathbb{Q}\right)$ is proved and $\mathscr{P}\left(\mathbb{Q}\right) \approx \mathscr{P}\left(\mathbb{N}\right) \approx \boldsymbol{2}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is assumed to be known.

Comment: @GregMartin Ha, I indeed thought of the first element, but did not think of $1/2$ as the next coefficient.

Comment: @GregMartin to answer your question about the codomain of $\theta$, probably this book is using the [Dedekind cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut) formulation of the real numbers, so that $\mathbb{R}\subset\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that

$$\theta(f)=\left\{q\in\Bbb Q:q<\sum_{i\ge 0}\frac{f(i)}{10^i}\right\}\,,$$

the Dedekind cut corresponding to the real number $\sum_{i\ge 0}\frac{f(i)}{10^i}$. No two real numbers in $[0,1]$ have have distinct decimal expansions whose digits are all $0$ or $1$, so $\theta$ must be injective.

To prove it, suppose that $f,g:\Bbb N\to\{0,1\}$, and $f\ne g$. Let $k\in\Bbb N$ be minimal such that $f(k)\ne g(k)$. Without loss of generality we may assume that $f(k)=0$ and $g(k)=1$. Then

$$\sum_{i=0}^kf(i)+\frac2{10^{k+1}}\in\theta(g)\setminus\theta(f)\,,$$

so $\theta(f)\ne\theta(g)$, and $\theta$ is an injection.

Comment: Should the addition be $2/10^{k+1}$ or $1/\left(2 \cdot 10^{k+1}\right)$?

Comment: @ZiqiFan: It’s correct as written: I need to add enough to make sure that the result is bigger than all of the sums $\sum_{i=0}^mf(i)$ for $m>k$. The real number corresponding to $f$ is at most $$\sum_{i=0}^kf(i)+0.\underbrace{00\ldots00}_{k}111\ldots<\sum_{i=0}^kf(i)+\frac2{10^{k+1}}\,.$$

Comment: If the context is about defining $\Bbb R$ in terms of Dedekind cuts, then I think an ideal solution wouldn't refer to "the real number $\sum_{i\ge0} \frac{f(i)}{10^i}$" at all. The second paragraph is great and, to me anyway, self-contained.

Comment: @GregMartin: I wrote it before the addition that mentions Dedekind cuts. But in any case I disagree: I think that mentioning the real number in question is a real aid to the intuition in thinking about what’s going on here.

Comment: mmmm I guess I mildly/partially disagree, but fair enough :)